# Kubuntu 20.04 freezes on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, freeze

My kubuntu 20.04 installation often (about 8 out of 10 times) gets stuck during the boot process. Using nomodeset or any other parameter i've found on the internet doesn't seem to help. I'm in a dual boot configuration. I've also removed the quiet splash parameters in the grub menu to see if i could get some information that way, the boot process seems to freeze at a different step every time.

My other OS(windows 10) installation works just fine, and i can use the system normally.

I was hoping that someone could help me troubleshoot this issue.

EDIT:

Here's the hardware specs:

i7 4770 @ 3.4Ghz,
16 GB DDR3 @ 1866MHz,
Nvidia RTX 2070 super,
Kubuntu installed on 500GB SSD, one other SSD present for the windows disk and one HDD present for storage.

EDIT2:

Maybe i should clarify that i am not at all experienced with linux distros. For ease of use i prefer (k)ubuntu as it seems the most 'mainstream.'

EDIT3:

As of yet (25-01) the problem persists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications.

Comment: hardware specs added

Comment: With a Nvidia graphics disable Secure Boot and install the recommended Nvidia drivers at Additional Drivers or with `sudo ubuntu-devices autoinstall`.

Comment: secure boot is disabled and  tested proprietary drivers are installed

Comment: Does the trouble persist if you use another distro? For example, testing it with Ubuntu, Manjaro, Mint, etc.

Comment: its worth giving it a try, although i have to say i prefer KDE over gnome

Comment: i've installed KDE neon, which from what i've read seems to be a little different from kubuntu under the hood. so far i didn't have any trouble during reboots, i'll try it for some time and if performance stays stable and good i can live with this solution.

Comment: i've spoken to soon, the problems have re-emerged. interestingly after having a session on windows. Same behaviour, just flat out freezing and me having to hard reboot the pc. i did get an error this time: AHCI controller not available, but searching for the issue has not yielded a good result yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing all the SATA cables and the PSU in my system i have no longer encountered this problem. I'm considering this issue resolved.

thanks to all